# Creating a barrel file in react (using .tsx)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

Here's my folder structure:

- src

  - assets
  - components
  - models

    - counter.tsx
    - index.ts

Code inside of models/index.tsx (the barrel file)

```
export * from "./counter";
```

Code inside models/counter.tsx

```
export default interface ICounter {
  id: number;
  value: number;
}
```

Import statement

```
import { ICounter } from "models";
```

The problem is I'm getting an error from my import statement saying that my barrel file has no exported member `ICounter`

[image: import error]

How do you create barrel files in .tsx?

Comment: How are you resolving the `'models'` import? Shouldn't it have to be a relative path?

Comment: 1. Please include the complete source of `models/index.tsx` and `counter.tsx`. 2. Please do not post error text as images.

Comment: i have a `baseUrl: "src"` property under compilerOptions in tsconfig.json

Comment: And how are you exporting `ICounter` in `counter.tsx`? Is it a named export?

Comment: I edited my original post to include code inside of counter.tsx

Comment: You are exporting `ICounter` as `default` and importing as named. Barrels have to be named. Remove `default` from the `ICounter` export.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file `index.ts`

```
export { blue } from './blue';
export { yellow} from './yellow';
export { green} from './green';
export { red} from './red';
```

source: https://hackernoon.com/react-project-architecture-using-barrels-d086146eb0f6

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use the named export instead of default export to works barrel export correctly. You can read [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-barrel-exports-organize-react-components/) to why you have to use named exports in barrel file. Therefore, if you change the models/counter.tsx file as below, your problem will resolve.

```js
export interface ICounter {
  id: number;
  value: number;
}
```